# Getting error: self' used in method call 'getliveData' before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm unable to get this error to be removed. I've used this function before without issue and even seen tutorials where this structure is done and the compiler doesn't complain but for some reason this keeps happening and i'm not sure why. I'm just trying to fetcha. document from Firestore.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import Foundation



class LiveStream: ObservableObject {

@Published var hptvlive: HPtvLiveData



init() {getliveData()}


func getliveData(){
    
    let  db = Firestore.firestore()

   let docRef = db.collection("HPtvLive").document("hptvlive")

    docRef.getDocument{ (document, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            
            print("error", error ?? "")
            return
        }
        if let document = document, document.exists{
            
            let data = document.data()
            if let data = data {
                print("data", data)
                self.hptvlive.title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                self.hptvlive.upnextText = data["upnextText"] as? String ?? ""
                self.hptvlive.description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
            }
        }




                }
            }




    }

struct HPtvLiveData {
var title: String
var upnextText: String
var description: String
var thumbnail: URL
var poster: URL
}
```

Comment: *I've used this function before without issue*. If `hptvlive` is not being initialized I doubt it. You have to do that in the `init` method. That’s what the error says, repeating a basic rule: All stored properties must be initialized before using `self`.

Comment: I tried that and it kept telling me it could not find hptvlive in scope

Comment: Format your code, the indentation is a mess, maybe the braces are not balanced properly.

Comment: To format, select all, then `Ctrl` + `i`

Comment: Echoing the first comment, there's no way this code ever compiled and if there are tutorials using this structure, there's an important element missing compared to what's shown here. Are you using missing an initializer after `@Published var hptvlive: HPtvLiveData`? or should it be an Optional?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 issues here:

1. You are setting hptvlive in an async callback, so when the init is returned, that value is still not initialized, it will be set only later when getDocument callback is invoked.
2. I am not sure this is how you should work with @Published info. But setting the entire object hptvlive to be published, you are not checking for changes per field inside that struct, but you are looking for the reference to the struct.
   If this is what you wish, then I would write:
   @Published var hptvlive: HPtvLiveData? = nil

This way you are starting with a reference to nil and later sets a value into it.

Another option, which I believe is more likely (but again, depends on how your view is going to use the info) is to:

let hptvlive = HPtvLiveData()

```
// instead of struct use:
class HPtvLiveData : ObservableObject {
   @Published var title: String = ""
   @Published var upnextText: String = ""
   @Published var description: String = ""
   @Published var thumbnail: URL?
   @Published var poster: URL?
   
   // For easy tracking of set / not set yet
   @Published var isDataAvailable = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, This is actually exactly what I did before I saw your comment and it satisfied the compiler, I just changed the data to optional (started to understand what I did wrong). My only real issue now is that Xcode is doing this weird prebuilding/indexing loop, so i'm unable to continue until I figure out how to stop it from doing that. But thanks for this.